# MS Intelli Mouse Optical not working on Mint Linux 15 64-bit

Tags: xorg, mouse

I have a *MS Intelli Mouse Optical* with *5 Buttons* and the side buttons are *not working*.

I have searched for a `xorg.conf` file but I couldn't find it.

*What can I do to make the mouse work like in Windows 7? (You know the plug & play stuff)*

Comment: Wow, mint Linux doesn't support my 15 years old 5 button mouse.

Comment: What do you expect the 5 buttons to do? I have no idea what “the plug & play stuff” in Windows 7 is. In my experience, extra mouse buttons usually do work out of the box, but no application does anything with them by default. To check if the buttons are recognized, run the program `xev` in a terminal and press the buttons over the xev window.

Comment: No, the side buttons are not recognized by the `xev` Event Tester Window. Are there any workarounds for this ?